# cannot add the item to shopping cart

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, cart

Started getting this error when I'm trying to add a product to the basket:

**cannot add the item to shopping cart**

the exception.log had the following error:

```
2013-04-02T14:45:35+00:00 DEBUG (7): Exception message: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`bespoken_mgn1`.`mgn_sales_flat_quote_item`, CONSTRAINT `FK_687093A92A4F71BEF47F9AC76B2E2F25` FOREIGN KEY (`quote_id`) REFERENCES `mgn_sales_flat_quote` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDA)
Trace: #0 /home6/bespoken/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home6/bespoken/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home6/bespoken/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home6/bespoken/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `mg...', Array)
#4 /home6/bespoken/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `mg...', Array)
#5 /home6/bespoken/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(574): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `mg...', Array)
#6 /home6/bespoken/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(453): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->insert('mgn_sales_flat_...', Array)
#7 /home6/bespoken/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(318): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->save(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item))
#8 /home6/bespoken/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php(751): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#9 /home6/bespoken/public_html/app/code/local/EmmanuelOrduna/UpdateProductPrice/Model/Observer.php(20): Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item->save()
#10 /home6/bespoken/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): EmmanuelOrduna_UpdateProductPrice_Model_Observer->updatePrice(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#11 /home6/bespoken/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(EmmanuelOrduna_UpdateProductPrice_Model_Observer), 'updatePrice', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#12 /home6/bespoken/public_html/app/Mage.php(447): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('sales_quote_add...', Array)
#13 /home6/bespoken/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php(874): Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_quote_add...', Array)
#14 /home6/bespoken/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php(1015): Mage_Sales_Model_Quote->addItem(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item))
#15 /home6/bespoken/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php(924): Mage_Sales_Model_Quote->_addCatalogProduct(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), '1')
#16 /home6/bespoken/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php(978): Mage_Sales_Model_Quote->addProductAdvanced(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), Object(Varien_Object), 'full')
#17 /home6/bespoken/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Cart.php(271): Mage_Sales_Model_Quote->addProduct(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), Object(Varien_Object))
#18 /home6/bespoken/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php(193): Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart->addProduct(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), Array)
#19 /home6/bespoken/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Checkout_CartController->addAction()
#20 /home6/bespoken/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('add')
#21 /home6/bespoken/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#22 /home6/bespoken/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#23 /home6/bespoken/public_html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#24 /home6/bespoken/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#25 {main}
```

#### Edit

I had an Observer module with issues causing a problem. Disabled it and all worked fine!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
#9 /home6/bespoken/public_html/app/code/local/EmmanuelOrduna/UpdateProductPrice/Model/Observer.php(20): Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item->save()
```

In this line, I can see that you have a Observer class that is trying to 
save a `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item` when an item is being added to the cart.

You do not need to call `save()` on the quote, whatever changes you do on the `quote` variable, it will be saved automatically later on as the variable is being passed by reference.